# Can you invoke stylizing commands in a .bib-file when using the BiBLaTeX apa package?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, formatting, apa-style

**This question has been heavily rewritten. That's why some of the comments and answers might be a little bit odd (they were responses to earlier versions of the question).**

I'm using the [BiBLaTeX apa](http://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=biblatex%20apa&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf&ei=gtevTp3YPMSh4gTX3cWeAQ&usg=AFQjCNGjdCL_4HjyCne-LViNCamJr2wG9w&sig2=fiONZydyPgQbXRa_-6drHQ) package in conjunction with a .bib-file (generated by [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/)) to create references. Now, in one of my titles, I would like some words to be in italics. Is it possible to invoke stylizing commands directly in the .bib-file?

Minimal (non)working example (taken from Lockstep):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {This is a thesis title with some \mkbibemph{emphasized words}},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {This is a book title with some \mkbibemph{emphasized words}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This just prints the whole title with italics (as specified by the apa style).

Comment: If I write `A \emph{title}` in the `title` field, then the word will be emphasized in the final printout. Would you show a minimal example, please?

Comment: Works for me also with `biblatex-apa`, so you'll have to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Also, check the `.bib` file generated by Mendeley. Maybe Mendeley tries to sanitize your input and goes over the top (i.e., removes `\mkbibemeph`).

Comment: @lockstep Darn it. You're right. Mendeley converts it like so: 'title = {{The $\backslash$mkbibemph\{Treason\} of Images [Painting]}}' when I write 'The \mkbibemph{Treason} of Images [Painting]' in Mendeley itself.

Comment: I'll probably just have to unsync my .bib-file from Mendeley and do the edits manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use commands like `\mkbibemph` in a `.bib` file, `biblatex` should apply the correct formatting. Note, however, that the built-in bibliography styles will by default print the titles of some entry types (e.g. `@book`) in italics, so `\mkbibemph` will result in upright text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {This is a thesis title with some \mkbibemph{emphasized words}},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {This is a book title with some \mkbibemph{emphasized words}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: In response to your edited question: Your original example doesn't compile for me, and if I replace

```
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
```

with

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
```

, `\mkbibemph` works as expected. (Note that `biblatex-apa` typesets thesis titles in italics.)

EDIT 2: Also, check the `.bib` file generated by Mendeley. Maybe Mendeley tries to sanitize your input and goes over the top (i.e., removes `\mkbibemph`).

Comment: Formally, this answers my question. However, I'm using the BiBLaTeX apa package "Invoked by adding the option '[style=apa]' when loading the biblatex package. This is what causes my problems.I'll try to rewrite my question.

Comment: How come the two different titles are different? The stylizing you've applied looks the same to me.

Comment: It's `@thesis` v. `@book` in the `.bib` file.

Comment: Right :) I see it now.